# Conversion of Image using MatplotLib or Pillow

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have an image of dimension (1000,1000,4) which I want to convert in (1000,1000,3). How to do this using either matplotlib or pillow module in python?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you have a Numpy array or a PIL Image? Also what do the current 4 channels represent? CMYK? RGBA?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would save your array as a numpy array, flatten it, and then reshape it. However you cannot convert a (1000,1000,4) into (1000,1000,3). A (1000,1000,4) has 1000 x 1000 x 4 elements which can not be converted into an array which stores 1000 x 1000 x 3 elements. You will have to get rid of some elements.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(your_array) 
arr.flatten().reshape((x dim,y dim ,z dim))
```